# Why encoding a string in php and in java is different from each other?

Tags: java, php

**PHP**

```
function encrypt($string) 
{
        $key_para = "AIBL_#0#0!0!@";
        $result = '';
        $test = "";
        for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) 
        {
            $char = substr($string, $i, 1);                     
            $a = ($i % strlen($key_para))-1;
            $keychar = substr($key_para, $a, 1);

            $inte = ord($char)+ord($keychar); 
            echo $i.'=';
            echo $inte;
            echo '</br>';                  
            $char = chr($inte);

            $result.=$char;
        }
    echo '</br>';
    echo $result;
    $base64t = base64_encode($result);
    $res = urlencode($base64t);
    $f_data = str_replace("%", "_", $res);

    return $f_data;
}
```

**Java**

```
public static String encrypt(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    String key_para= "AIBL_#0#0!0!@";
    String result ="";
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        int a = (i % key_para.length()) -1 ;
        char keyChar ;
        if(a < 0) {
            keyChar = key_para.charAt(key_para.length()+a);
            } else if(a > 0) {
            keyChar = key_para.charAt(a);
            } else {
            keyChar = key_para.charAt(0);
        }
        int temp = ((int) ch + (int) keyChar);
        System.out.println(i+"="+temp);
        ch = (char) temp;
        System.out.println(i+"="+ch);
        result += ch;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    String enc=java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result.getBytes());
    String res = URLEncoder.encode(enc, "UTF-8");
    String f_data = res.replace('%','_') ;
    return f_data;
}
```

**String to be encrypted:**

```
"mobileno=01911222333&accountno=0021120125225&pin=1234"
```

**Output should be:**

```
"rbCrq7jEkZ9gYFJpUnFze3R_2FklZWhJOEn5autbexiY9TYlRhU2BScnZ7dIGFk5mRbVJiVHQ_3D"
```

**Java Output:**

```
"rbCrq7jEPz9gYFJpUnFze3R_2FP1ZWPz8_2FPz_2ButbexPz9TYlRhU2BScnZ7dD8_2FPz8_2FbVJiVHQ_3D"
```

The logic in both the languages is same but their output is different.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `result` the same in both versions before your use Base64 encode on the string?

Comment: Also I see your Java code has extended logic with the `keyChar` variable, e.g. what is this `keyChar = key_para.charAt(key_para.length()+a);`? That should throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException `!?.

Comment: ­°««¸Ä??``RiRqs{t?VV?????®µ·±??SbTaS`Rrv{t?????mRbTt  this is in java        
�����đ�``RiRqs{t�VV�����������SbTaS`Rrv{t�����mRbTt   this is in php before encoding

Comment: Try with hard coded strings and compare...

Comment: Your Java code yields me `wq3CsMKrwqvCuMOEwpHCn2BgUmlScXN7dH_2FCklZWwoTCk8KEwp_2FClsKuwrXCt8KxwonCj1NiVGFTYFJydnt0woHChcKTwpnCkW1SYlR0` for your test string.

Comment: May be u have a different version of java or may be something is wrong with url encoder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well, except for one thing: you're calling [`str.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) without argument:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

That's why [my output was different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749496/why-encoding-a-string-in-php-and-in-java-is-different-from-each-other#comment78458956_45749496) than yours.

To fix this, you need to specify the encoding of the bytes. If you specify the ISO 8859-1 charset, it'll work as expected.

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))
```

---

If you want to avoid encoding problems, you'd better use bytes instead of characters. [A character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)) is in fact a different concept, and needs its own encoding to be represented in bytes. So you could replace `String result` by `List<Byte>` or other form of byte buffer.